# Update field in SQL on particular line matching search syntax

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite3 called `MachineData` with the following headers:

- ResourceId *(Primary Key)*
- MachineName
- PrimaryUser

The table has the `ResourceId` populated and I need to do a lookup against the `ResourceId` and inject data along the row.

I have tried the following statements, but it doesn't like my syntax. Any help would be appreciated?

```bsh
INSERT INTO MachineData (PrimaryUser) VALUES ('Mickey Mouse') WHERE ResourceId LIKE '1001'
```

and also

```
INSERT INTO MachineData (PrimaryUser) VALUES ('Mickey Mouse') WHERE (SELECT ResourceId FROM MachineData LIKE '1001')
```

and also

```
INSERT INTO MachineData (PrimaryUser) VALUES ('Mickey Mouse') WHERE ResourceId EQUALS '1001'
```

None of these have decided to play nice, always giving me logic error.

The table looks like this:

`TABLENAME: MachineData`

```
| ResourceId | MachineName | PrimaryUser | 
|============|=============|=============|
| 1001       |             |             |
| 1002       |             |             |
| 1003       |             |             |
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
| ResourceId | MachineName  | PrimaryUser  | 
|============|==============|==============|
| 1001       |              | Mickey Mouse |
| 1002       |              |              |
| 1003       |              |              |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want an `update`?

```
UPDATE MachineData
    SET PrimaryUser = 'Mickey Mouse'
    WHERE ResourceId LIKE '1001';
```

I am guessing that `ResourceId` is a number.  If so, you should not use string operations:

```
UPDATE MachineData
    SET PrimaryUser = 'Mickey Mouse'
    WHERE ResourceId LIKE 1001;
```

Comment: I set `ResourceId` as TEXT type because sometimes it's actually got letters in it too. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: @Danijel-JamesW . . . Then use `= '1001'` for equality and `like` if you want to use wildcards.

Comment: This worked: `UPDATE MachineData SET PrimaryUser='Mickey Mouse' WHERE ResourceId='1001'` Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

What you have tried was to insert a line which is already in the table. That's why you are getting the error. If the primary key already exists in the given table, you cant use `INSERT` keyword. Use `UPDATE` query as below.

```
UPDATE MachineData SET PrimaryUser = 'Mickey Mouse' WHERE ResourceId LIKE '1001'
```

Comment: Got it sorted. Thank you for explaining. I was reading the docs and couldn’t work out why it wasn’t working based on how I understood the doc.